# Como puedo simular que se presiona un boton dentro de un WebView en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, vb.net, webview

Estoy haciendo una app para descargar videos 
lo que hace es que el webview se dirige a una pgina web para descaragar el video y lo que quiero hacer es simular que se presiona el boton de descargar dentro de un webview pero sin presionarlo en el web view para que el usuario no tenga que presionarlo, sino presionar un boton fuera y que por medio de codigo este simule el presionamiento del boton dentro del webview como en vb.net

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_del_boton").InvokeMember("click")
```

pero estoy buscando y no encuentro nada al respecto

Comment: Bienvenido..Omar..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: el botón esta dentro de lo cargado en el WebView, afuera, donde? debes especificar, agrega el layout que estas usando-